# SQLite Database security in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, security

I am working on a app in which I have to store data in SQLite Database, I want to secure mapp database, so that any other outsides can not access confidential information of SQLite Database. Please suggest me a suitable answer.

Comment: You have to encrypt the data within the tables.  Keeping the key secret will be almost impossible however.

Comment: I don't know what to do. Please give any idea

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no encryption support in the SQLite version shipped with iOS.

One option is [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net) which has a community edition with a  BSD-style license or a commercial edition. They [explicitly support iOS](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial).

There's even a [project that provides SQLCipher support for Core Data](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data).

Answer (score 0):

Use this class by

Rob Napier - [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

to encrypt the data before storing it in SQLite. And while retrieving data provide the same key which you used to encrypt it.

Comment: Since this is generic class to decrypt/encrypt data, this means that you need'd to somehow make sure the SQLite DB gets encrypted. For example, on app start decrypt the encrypted DB (let's call it _alpha_) to a temporary file (let's call it _omega_). Then you need to open _omega_ with SQLite. You need to re-encode _omega_ and overwrite _alpha_ at appropriate times. Certainly a way to do it but it'd feel way too tricky to me.

Comment: while encrypting the whole DB, we lose the ability to perform any queries on it except to decrypt the entire DB. My suggestion is why not encrypt only the data sensitive columns (on assumption only few data points in the DB are sensitive) in sqlite, and perform last moment decryption only when needed.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you'd like to do. You'll lose the ability to do `LIKE` queries, and how do you encrypt numbers? As strings? You'd have to maintain a wrapper that takes care of encrypting and decrypting every operation. You _can_ do that, but I'd find that even more cumbersome than en/decrypting the whole DB (maybe you missed my part about operating on _omega_ with SQLite, so once it's decrypted you'd use the DB in the usual way; you just need to make sure re-encrypt the DB file from time to time and overwrite _alpha_).